# '%' getting interpreted as '0' when inputting URL into address bar

Tags: blueprism

Percentage sign ('%') is getting interpreted as ('0') when inputting URL into address bar from Blue Prism for a SharePoint website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is to do with the % symbol being interpreted as a command. You need to use curly brackets for it to be used successfully.

Something like this should do it

Replace(Replace("https://health.sharepoint.com/sites/in/Standard/Forms/My%20Claims.aspx","%","{%}"),")","{%}")

Answer (score 0):

While Eoin2111's answer is correct, generally speaking when editing URL, you should make sure to encode it (remove spaces, special characters etc.).
One of the ways to encode URL is [HttpUtility.UrlEncode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-5.0). The usage of this and some other useful methods is very well described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp).