# .NET Httpclient encoding a url but I dont want it to

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, encoding, httpclient

I have a url with the pipe | symbol.  When I call it from Httpclient it is getting encoded to %7C.

I read there was a 'dont escape' on the Uri in .NET but that has now been marked obsolete.

Is there anything I can do so that this | is not encoded on the request?

The url I am building is like:

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = _httpClient.PrepareRequestMessage($"your/notstandardquerystringparam:term|otherterm", HttpMethod.Get, null, null);
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

The service I am calling is failing when the | symbol is getting encoded.  I need it passed to the service as the actual | symbol

Comment: What part of the uri do you want to use the symbol in? And why is it not okay to escape it?

Comment: @NineBerry - I added some clarifications to the question

Comment: There is no `PrepareRequestMessage` method on the [`HttpClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0). Is that method introducing this encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an interesting post that might help: [URL Encoding using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp?rq=1)

Personally, I am using a library like `RestSharp` to do this.

I am not sure where that pipe needs to be. In the URL segment or query? I assume the query parameters in the following example since that is the only place where I could imagine you need a pipe.

```cs
using var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/api");

var request = new RestRequest("your/endpoint");

// the last parameter encode=false will disable encoding
request.AddQueryParameter("queryname", "term|otherterm", false); 

var response = await client.GetAsync(request);

// GET https://example.com/api/your/endpoint?queryname=term|otherterm
```