# how to replace special characters in file names

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace, filenames

We are in the process of moving to OneDrive for Business. To store files in OneDrive you can't have the following charactes in the filename:
/:*?"<>|#%
Additionally, a file name that begins with a tilde (~) isn't supported.
I would like to search and replace the special character with a dash.
Anyone have a batch file or powershell script?

Comment: Please be aware that there are other rules for OneDrive filenames than invalid characters so simply replacing characters is, in general, not sufficient. Consult [Invalid Filename Check](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18494401/).

Comment: Dour - I appreciate the response, but I'm not sure how that post relates. Here is the actual page from Microsoft explaining filename limitations. https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933738

Comment: FYI, one problem I've encountered in the past is name clashes, whereby the script alters a file and the new name matches an existing file. My preferred approach these days is to have the script report any bad names, and let a person deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, `\ / : * ? " < > |` aren't allowed in Windows filenames either, so most of your list is already a non-issue.  Assuming that list of characters is complete, all that remain are hashes, percents, and leading tildes.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: replace ~ only if first char of filename
for %%I in ("~*") do (
    set "file=%%~I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo %%~I -^> -!file:~1!
    ren "%%~I" "-!file:~1!"
    endlocal
)

:: replace # or % everywhere in filename
for %%d in (# %%) do (
    for %%I in ("*%%d*") do (
        set "file=%%~I"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo %%~I -^> !file:%%d=-!
        ren "%%~I" "!file:%%d=-!"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

But as Dour points out, this only fixes some of the problems.  Your file uploads [might still require some hand-holding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18494870/1683264).  Or who knows?  This could solve all your worldly problems.  *shrug*

---

**Edit:** O.P. asked about adding `/r` to the `for` loops to make the replacements recursive.  You *could* do that with a few tweaks, but you'll end up looping through the file list 3 times -- once for each symbol you're replacing.  I suggest this would be a more efficient approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto usage
pushd "%~1"

for /r %%I in (*) do (
    set "file=%%~nxI"
    if "!file:~0,1!"=="~" (
        set "file=-!file:~1!"
    )
    for %%d in (# %%) do (
        if not "!file!"=="!file:%%d=!" (
            set "file=!file:%%d=-!"
        )
    )
    if not "!file!"=="%%~nxI" (
        echo %%~fI -^> !file!
        ren "%%~fI" "!file!"
    )
)

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 pathname
echo To operate on the current directory, use a dot as the pathname.
echo Example: %~nx0 .
```

**Edit 2:** Added argument syntax.

Comment: Thanks rojo. It works great at the current folder so I tried adding /r after "for" to recurse the subfolders. It seems to find the files, but says the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @cwhitmore try the updated tweaks and see what happens.

Comment: rojo - That worked great and didn't clobber my bang symbols. I added the following to allow this to run against different directories; 
%myvar%
pushd %myvar%
It works fine, but is there a way to require a variable so the batch file won't run unless it's specified?

Comment: Oops, had to edit my response. See above.

Comment: @cwhitmore You mean require an argument, like `batfile.bat c:\path\to\run`?

Comment: Yes. I'd like the argument to be required.

Comment: @cwhitmore added.  If you have any additional feature requests, you should post a new question.  But it would be a good idea to describe what effort you have made to find the solution to your question, and say where you're getting stuck.  For now, glad I could help!

Comment: I got this working below, but after it runs it takes me to the directory that I passed in argument. How do I stay at directory where I started?
<code>
@@echo off
IF [%1]==[] goto Continue 
pushd %1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%I in (*) do (
    set "file=%%~nxI"
    if "!file:~0,1!"=="~" (
        set "file=-!file:~1!"
    )
    for %%d in (# %%) do (
        if not "!file!"=="!file:%%d=!" (
            set "file=!file:%%d=-!"
        )
    )
    if not "!file!"=="%%~nxI" (
        echo %%~fI -^> !file!
        ren "%%~fI" "!file!"
    )
)
Exit /B
:Continue
@echo Enter directory

Comment: Move the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line below `pushd` and replace `pushd` with `cd`.  You should really keep the quotes in the `if` statement, rather than brackets.  `if "%~1"=="" goto Continue`.  If you have spaces in the path name, the bracket notation will break.

Comment: How do I format code? I tried using {} and selecting code and hitting CTRL  K

Comment: It's done with a `<-- language: lang-js -->` meta tag.  [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79591/275822) for details.  There's no prettify library for dos / batch, but js does pretty well.  If you're talking about `formatting code within comments`, just surround your code with backticks (the `\`` character).

Comment: If I change pushd to cd it won't check subdirectories, but it does stay in same directory I run the script from.

Comment: Post a new question with your current code.