# Check whether a path is valid

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, path

I am just wondering: I am looking for a way to validate if a given path is valid.
*(Note: I do not want to check if a file is existing! I only want to proof the validity of the path - So if a file could possibly exists at the location)*.

Problem is, I can't find anything in the .Net API.
Due to the many formats and locations that Windows supports, I'd rather use something MS-native.

Since the function should be able to check against:

> - Relative Paths (./)
> - Absolute Paths (c:\tmp)
> - UNC-Pathes (\some-pc\c$)
> - NTFS-Limitations like the full path 1024 chars - If I am not mistaken exceeding the path will make a file inaccessible for many
>     internal Windows functions. Renaming it with Explorer still works
> - Volume GUID Paths : "\?\Volume{GUID}\somefile.foo

Does anyone have a function like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How check if given string is legal (allowed) file name under Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows)

Answer (score 69):

Try [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-5.0):

- The string is not correctly escaped.

  ```
    http://www.example.com/path???/file name
  ```
- The string is an absolute Uri that represents an implicit file Uri.

  ```
    c:\\directory\filename
  ```
- The string is an absolute URI that is missing a slash before the path.

  ```
    file://c:/directory/filename
  ```
- The string contains unescaped backslashes even if they are treated as forward slashes.

  ```
    http:\\host/path/file
  ```
- The string represents a hierarchical absolute Uri and does not contain "://".

  ```
    www.example.com/path/file
  ```
- The parser for the Uri.Scheme indicates that the original string was not well-formed.

  ```
    The example depends on the scheme of the URI.
  ```

Comment: This sounds very promising... I take a closer look at it! I'll drop a line after I have evaluated if the method serves my purpose! Thanks abatishchev

Comment: This returns false for `@"foo\bar\baz"`, which is a perfectly valid relative path...

Comment: Thomas: What UriKind did you specify? You can use Absolute, Relative or AbsoluteOrRelative.

Comment: Even with UriKind as Relative or AbsoluteOrRelative it didn't work for relative paths like Thomas mentioned.  I ended up using Patko's answer instead & it works for my purposes.

Comment: I found that a path such as \\computerName\Dir Name With Spaces\fileName throws an exception when using IsWellFormedUriString (contrary to my initial expectation), because the spaces aren't properly encoded.  I found that I could just use the Uri(string) constructor as my validation, thereby, not having to properly encode the string before validating.

Comment: Does not work with a simple path like "\\myserver\mypath" with releative or absolute uri kind.

Comment: This doesn't work for all this exemples.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx
The documentation say :
"The string is considered poorly formed, causing the method to return false, if any of the following conditions occur :
The string is not correctly escaped.
http://www.contoso.com/path???/file name
The string is an absolute Uri that represents an implicit file Uri.
c:\\directory\filename
…"

Comment: Returns false on a perfectly fine file path.

Comment: Answer says `IsWellFormedUriString` but links to `IsWellFormedOriginalString`. Though the page seems to indicate the former has special behavior with .Net 4.5+, I believe the main difference is that one is static and one is an instance method.

Answer (score 32):

Or use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) as suggested in [In C# check that filename is *possibly* valid (not that it exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/in-c-check-that-filename-is-possibly-valid-not-that-it-exists).

Comment: Using the solution posted by "LamdaComplex", on the same thread, seems more accurate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11636052/2546739

Answer (score 14):

I haven't had any problems with the code below. (Relative paths must start with '/' or '\').

```
private bool IsValidPath(string path, bool allowRelativePaths = false)
{
    bool isValid = true;

    try
    {
        string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);

        if (allowRelativePaths)
        {
            isValid = Path.IsPathRooted(path);
        }
        else
        {
            string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
            isValid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(root.Trim(new char[] { '\\', '/' })) == false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

For example these would return false:

```
IsValidPath("C:/abc*d");
IsValidPath("C:/abc?d");
IsValidPath("C:/abc\"d");
IsValidPath("C:/abc<d");
IsValidPath("C:/abc>d");
IsValidPath("C:/abc|d");
IsValidPath("C:/abc:d");
IsValidPath("");
IsValidPath("./abc");
IsValidPath("./abc", true);
IsValidPath("/abc");
IsValidPath("abc");
IsValidPath("abc", true);
```

And these would return true:

```
IsValidPath(@"C:\\abc");
IsValidPath(@"F:\FILES\");
IsValidPath(@"C:\\abc.docx\\defg.docx");
IsValidPath(@"C:/abc/defg");
IsValidPath(@"C:\\\//\/\\/\\\/abc/\/\/\/\///\\\//\defg");
IsValidPath(@"C:/abc/def~`!@#$%^&()_-+={[}];',.g");
IsValidPath(@"C:\\\\\abc////////defg");
IsValidPath(@"/abc", true);
IsValidPath(@"\abc", true);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
private bool IsValidPath(string path)
{
    Regex driveCheck = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\$");
    if (!driveCheck.IsMatch(path.Substring(0, 3))) return false;
    string strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
    strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars += @":/?*" + "\"";
    Regex containsABadCharacter = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars) + "]");
    if (containsABadCharacter.IsMatch(path.Substring(3, path.Length - 3)))
        return false;

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(path));
    if (!dir.Exists)
        dir.Create();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Creating a folder is a nasty side effect for a boolean that you think is going to just check a string for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this code:

```
try
{
  Path.GetDirectoryName(myPath);
}
catch
{
  // Path is not valid
}
```

I'm not sure it covers all the cases...

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of good solutions in here, but as none of then check if the path is rooted in an *existing drive* here's another one:

```
private bool IsValidPath(string path)
{
    // Check if the path is rooted in a driver
    if (path.Length < 3) return false;
    Regex driveCheck = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\$");
    if (!driveCheck.IsMatch(path.Substring(0, 3))) return false;

    // Check if such driver exists
    IEnumerable<string> allMachineDrivers = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(drive => drive.Name);
    if (!allMachineDrivers.Contains(path.Substring(0, 3))) return false;

    // Check if the rest of the path is valid
    string InvalidFileNameChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
    InvalidFileNameChars += @":/?*" + "\"";
    Regex containsABadCharacter = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(InvalidFileNameChars) + "]");
    if (containsABadCharacter.IsMatch(path.Substring(3, path.Length - 3)))
        return false;
    if (path[path.Length - 1] == '.') return false;

    return true;
}
```

This solution does **not** take relative paths into account.

Comment: It passes my tests, just missing the null check.. it could be added at first condition `if (path == null || path.Length < 3) return false;`

Comment: another thing is, ```d:\folder1\``` is considered not valid path due to `d` being small-letter, I solved it by adding `path = path?.ToUpper();` at the beginning of the function..

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have come is by trying to create it, and seeing if it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Get the invalid chars from `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars();` and check if your string (Directory path) contains those or not.

Comment: This isn't entirely valid.  "C:\new.folder" is valid while "C:\newfolder." is not.  '.' is a valid character for a paths/filenames, but not at the end of the uri.

Answer (score 1):

this accepts a path that could equate to a valid relative path too

```
string path = "yourPath";
bool pathIsValid = null;
try
{ 
    Path.GetFullPath(path);
    pathIsValid = true;
}
catch
{
    pathIsValid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool IsValidPath(string path)
{
    Regex driveCheck = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\$");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) || path.Length < 3)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!driveCheck.IsMatch(path.Substring(0, 3)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var x1 = (path.Substring(3, path.Length - 3));
    string strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
    strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars += @":?*";
    Regex containsABadCharacter = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(strTheseAreInvalidFileNameChars) + "]");

    if (containsABadCharacter.IsMatch(path.Substring(3, path.Length - 3)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var driveLetterWithColonAndSlash = Path.GetPathRoot(path);

    if (!DriveInfo.GetDrives().Any(x => x.Name == driveLetterWithColonAndSlash))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of x1?

Answer (score -4):

[Directory.Exists?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx)

Comment: "[...] do not want to check if a file is existing!"

Comment: That test for the directory existing, not for it being a valid path (where one might exist, or be created, given proper priviledges)

Comment: @Jason - It doesn't check the file, only the containing folder.

Comment: but a valid directory path could still not exist.

Answer (score -4):

You could try using Path.IsPathRooted() in combination with Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() to make sure the path is half-way okay.