# How to detect that a file does not exist?

Tags: c#, .net

A 3rd party library errors out when the file paths are invalid.  We attempted to handle this case using `File.Exists()` thinking that it would return false when the file path contains invalid characters, but **it returns true**.

This is strange (see the extra spaces and period)

```
    string wrong = "myfolder1\\myfolder2\\myfile.txt      .";
    bool x = File.Exists(wrong);
```

Is there a way to clean up the file path?

`new FileInfo(wrong).Name` does not clean it up.

Our main purpose is to reliably determine if the file path is valid before sending it into the 3rd party library.  I almost feel stupid asking this question because I think that File.Exists() ought to be doing this.

(We're on .NET 4.0)

Comment: I would look into Regex.Replace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx
Static version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say: _"We have a file at path X. While the path X may look weird, the file exists visibly in Explorer at X and `File.Exists(X)` returns `true`. Now when we feed string X to a library where it expects a path, the library explodes"_. What exactly want you to do? Change a path that the system thinks is correct, in order to keep the library happy? Into what do you want to change the path then?

Comment: I think I have just discovered a bug Windows Explorer: if I rename a file to its name + trailing dot, the file vanishes. But the file is actually still there, with the same name and it reappears after F5.

Comment: _when the file path contains invalid characters_ Your example does not contain any illegal characters. ;-)

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow A period is an illegal character if it is the last character in the filename.

Comment: @CodeCaster As I understand it, there is no file called `myfile.txt      .`. There is a file called `myfile.txt` and Windows treats the two names as if they were the same, but they are not same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The windows API trims trailing periods and spaces from filenames, if it was anything other than a period it would have worked.

See [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more info.

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

---

I don't know if it will work but you ***may*** be able to bypass the shell by using the `\\?\` prefix, try `File.Exists(@"\\?\C:\myfolder1\myfolder2\myfile.txt      .");` and see if that works (I can't test this moment right now, if it does not let me know and I will remove this section.)

Comment: @CodeCaster What is not true about the fact that the API of `File.Exists`is trimming trailing periods and spaces? This question is not about the creation of files, this is about testing for existence. Also the quote I put in says exactly what you said **"Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not."** File.Exists passes through the shell, and therfor trims the characters.

Comment: See also this question on whether or not a path is valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198392/check-whether-a-path-is-valid