# Check if path is a possible (valid) location to save a file in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, validation

Is there some method or combination thereof in the .NET API that I can pass a full path i.e. "C:\Directory\File.Ext" to, and check if I can create a file at that location. It would presumably return true or false.

For example,

```
C:\Directory\file.ext         : true, unless no permission to write there.
C:\Directory\??&#.kc2         : false
asdf                          : false
X:\Directory\file.ext         : false, if no X: drive exists
\\local-pc\directory\file.ext : true
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198392/check-whether-a-path-is-valid

Comment: You're looking for [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And @YuvalItzchakov has a good answer as well if you're looking if you can save there.

Comment: These kind of tests are worth very little on a multitasking operating system.  They do *not* promise that your file operation won't fail.  Because a nanosecond after you test, another process can still make the location inaccessible.  Leaving you with a serious head-scratcher (I checked, but it still failed!)  You can't skip try/catch around the operation, so just don't bother checking up front.

Comment: Use `try - catch`?  This would catch multiple exceptions (e.g., bad path, permissions, etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the more easier method is to try write to this path (especially UNC paths can be a problem) and try to **handle exception** if something goes wrong.

Moreover even if you create method which will check permissions, paths, etc. you will have to anyway make exception handler, because something could change between method invocations