# How can I check if the path entered by user is valid or not?

Tags: c#

I have found this code while I was busy searching for an answer!

```
private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog saveFileDialogBrowse = new OpenFileDialog();
    saveFileDialogBrowse.Filter = "Pcap file|*.pcap";
    saveFileDialogBrowse.Title = "Save an pcap File";
    saveFileDialogBrowse.ShowDialog();
    var pcapFile = saveFileDialogBrowse.FileName; //do whatever you like with the selected filename

    if (pcapFile != "")
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pcapFile);
        txtFilePath.Text = fileInfo.FullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you consider valid?

Comment: File.Exists() for files and Directory.Exists() for directories

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198392/check-whether-a-path-is-valid

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way.

You can use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)  to check for file existence on the path, but a change can still happen before the execution of the next line. Your best option is to combine `File.Exists` with `try-catch` to catch any possible exceptions.

```
private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog saveFileDialogBrowse = new OpenFileDialog();
    saveFileDialogBrowse.Filter = "Pcap file|*.pcap";
    saveFileDialogBrowse.Title = "Save an pcap File";
    saveFileDialogBrowse.ShowDialog();
    var pcapFile = saveFileDialogBrowse.FileName; //do whatever you like with the selected filename
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(pcapFile))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pcapFile);
            txtFilePath.Text = fileInfo.FullName;
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
        //Log and handle
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log and handle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**File.Exists**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string fullPath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
bool fileExists = File.Exists(fullPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `File.Exists` method, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).