# How to test for "The path is not of a legal form."

Tags: .net, string, file-io

I get a *The path is not of a legal form* error when trying to obtain

```
IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(myString)
```

... where (in this case) myString is an empty string.

It would be easy to test for an empty string first.

However is there a more comprehensive test against a string, so that this error can be avoided for all kinds of invalid myString?

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198392/check-whether-a-path-is-valid

Comment: @user469104 yep, thanks. funny that the error "The path is not of a legal form." ... which is what i searched for ... doesn't appear anywhere in that long established question

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but here is a simple try catch solution

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the directory information of the path. Return null if path is not in legal form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDirectoryName(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```