# Sanitizing a file path in C# without compromising the drive letter

Tags: c#, filenames, filepath

I need to process some file paths in C# that potentially contain illegal characters, for example:

```
C:\path\something\output_at_13:26:43.txt
```

in that path, the `:`s in the timestamp make the filename invalid, and I want to replace them with another safe character.

I've searched for solutions here on SO, but they seem to be all based around something like:

```
path = string.Join("_", path.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
```

or similar solutions. These solutions however are not good, because they screw up the drive letter, and I obtain an output of:

```
C_\path\something\output_at_13_26_43.txt
```

I tried using `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` but it still doesn't work, because it doesn't include the `:` in the illegal characters, so it doesn't replace the ones in the filename.

So, after figuring that out, I tried doing this:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string file = Path.GetFileName(path);
file = string.Join(replacement, file.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
dir = string.Join(replacement, dir.Split(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()));

path = Path.Combine(dir, file);
```

but this is not good either, because the `:`s in the filename seem to interfere with the `Path.GetFilename()` logic, and it only returns the last piece after the last `:`, so I'm losing pieces of the path.

How do I do this "properly" without hacky solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198392/check-whether-a-path-is-valid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/in-c-sharp-check-that-filename-is-possibly-valid-not-that-it-exists

Comment: The drive letter is always going to be 2 chars long, so you should do something like `string driveLetter = path.Substring(0, 2); path = path.Substring(2, path.Length-2);` thus you have "C:" in `driveLetter` and "\path\something\output_at_13:26:43.txt" in `path`. Apply the replacement in `path` and do a `Path.Combine(driveLetter, path);`

Comment: You beat me to it @ikerbera. You can leave out the second parameter in the second substring call, though.

Comment: @ikerbera - "The drive letter is always going to be 2 chars long" but only if it's present, which it doesn't have to be (e.g. relative paths, UNC paths).

Comment: @ikerbera: this doesn't work very well, because that will also replace the `\`s in the path (which are not legal for a filename). At the moment I'm using a similar solution, consisting of splitting the string manually on the last `\` and processing the left part as path and the right part as filename. I was wondering if there was a better solution tho.

Comment: You should probably do the clean up at the moment you generate a filename, rather than constructing an absolute path and attempting to clean it up afterwards.  E.g. `C:\path\something\output_on_21/12/2018.txt` contains no invalid path characters, so can't easily be cleaned up, but probably isn't what was intended.

Comment: @Joe: unfortunately, the paths come from and external application that I have no control over, so I have to work with what I get.

Comment: @Master_T I don't think there's anything that can help you with that, appart from string manipulation. You can use `Path.GetPathRoot` and `Path.IsPathRooted` to make your life easier. @Joe you're right, I didn't take into account if the drive letter is present. An `if (Path.GetPathRoot(path))` before processing the path should work.

Comment: @Master_T, sounds like a strange setup.  Is it only the filename part that can contain illegal characters?  If so you could use `Path.GetDirectoryName` to split off the directory, and do string manipulation on the filename part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should make sure that you only receive valid filenames.

If you can't, and you're certain your directory names will be, you could split the path the last backslash (assuming Windows) and reassemble the string:

```
public static string SanitizePath(string path)
{
    var lastBackslash = path.LastIndexOf('\\');

    var dir = path.Substring(0, lastBackslash);
    var file = path.Substring(lastBackslash, path.Length - lastBackslash);

    foreach (var invalid in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
    {
        file = file.Replace(invalid, '_');
    }

    return dir + file;
}
```

Comment: "Split on last backslash",  or slash: ideally using `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` to be OS-independent .NET Core ready.

Comment: I went with this solution in the end, simple but effective in my case.

Comment: Why look for the last backslash instead of using `Path.GetFileName`?

Comment: @Sefe because the OP claims _"because the :s in the filename seem to interfere with the Path.GetFilename() logic, and it only returns the last piece after the last :"_.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a simple sanitizer that iterates each character and knows when to expect the colon as a drive separator. This one will catch any combination of letter A-Z followed directly by a ":". It will also detect path separators and not escape them. It will not detect whitespace at the beginning of the input string, so in case your input data might come with them, you will have to trim it first or modify the sanitizer accordingly:

```
enum ParserState {
    PossibleDriveLetter,
    PossibleDriveLetterSeparator,
    Path
}

static string SanitizeFileName(string input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    ParserState state = ParserState.PossibleDriveLetter;
    foreach(char current in input) {
        if (((current >= 'a') && (current <= 'z')) || ((current >= 'A') && (current <= 'Z'))) {
            output.Append(current);
            if (state == ParserState.PossibleDriveLetter) {
                state = ParserState.PossibleDriveLetterSeparator;
            }
            else {
                state = ParserState.Path;
            }
        }
        else if ((current == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) ||
            (current == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar) ||
            ((current == ':') && (state == ParserState.PossibleDriveLetterSeparator)) ||
            !Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(current)) {

            output.Append(current);
            state = ParserState.Path;
        }
        else {
            output.Append('_');
            state = ParserState.Path;
        }
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

You can [try it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8OIZIe).

Comment: I think @Master_T was thinking about some method already existing in the .Net environment instead of having to make his own function. This is a very good solution, though.

Comment: @ikerbera: I don't know any built-in method that does that. I don't consider this solution "hacky" though, so I'd think it's within the scope of the question.

Comment: +1 for interesting solution, although a bit overkill for what I need here, so I went with CodeCaster's one. Thanks.