# Regex to disallow all symbols that windows doesnt allow in its file/folder names

Tags: c#, regex

The symbols not allowed in filename or folder name in windows are `\ / : * ? " < > |`. I wrote a regex for it but not able to write regex to exclude " (double quotes).

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\\\/\:\*\?\'\<\>\|]+$");
```

Tried as below but it didnt work:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\\\/\:\*\?\'\<\>\|&quot;]+$");
```

EDIT:
I am particularly looking for code with regex itself and hence its not a duplicate.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `^[^\\\/:*?"<>|]+$` ? Assuming you want to match a filename not containing those characters.

Comment: Why don't you just escape double quote with `\"`?

Comment: In C#, there is a special method that you may uuse to check if a filename is valid. No need to use a regex.

Comment: @zipa To escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal it should be doubled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C# check that filename is \*possibly\* valid (not that it exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/in-c-sharp-check-that-filename-is-possibly-valid-not-that-it-exists)

Comment: @dnickless: I am particularly looking for code with regex itself and hence its not duplicate to above question.

Comment: @Paul-Etienne: Its right but as Wiktor said, we will have to escape it with a double literal. Thanks Wiktor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Allrameest answer using `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` is probably the one you should use.

What I wanted to address is the fact that your regex is actually wrong or very ineffective (I don't know what exectly you wanted to do).

So, using:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[\\\/\:\*\?\'\<\>\|]+$");
```

mean you match a string which consists ONLY of "forbidden" characters (BTW, I think single quote `'` is not invalid). Is it what you want? Don't think so. What you did is:

- `^` start of the string
- `[...]+` invalid characters only (at least once)
- `$` end of the string

Maybe you wanted `@"^[^...]+$"` (hat used twice)?

Anyway, solution for your problem (with regex) is:

- don't use `^` or `$` just try to find any of those and bomb out quickly
- in raw string (the one starting with `@"`) you escape double quotes by doubling it.

So, the right regex is:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[\\\/\:\*\?\""\<\>\|]");
if (regex.Match(filename).Success) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Bad filename");
}
```

Just find any and bomb out.

---

UPDATE by @JohnLBevan

```
var regex = new Regex(
    "[" + Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())) + "]");
if (regex.Match(filename).Success) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Bad filename");
}
```

(Not using `string.Format(...)` as this Regex should be static and precompiled anyway)

Comment: Or combine your answers `var regex = new Regex(string.Format("^[^{0}]$", Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()))));` / `var regex = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()))));`

Comment: @Milosz: Perfect answer i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Regex you could do something like this:

```
var invalidChars = new HashSet<char>(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
var invalid = input.Any(chr => invalidChars.Contains(chr));
```

Comment: I am particularly looking for code with regex itself. But this solution works too. Thanks.