# How to prevent illegal file and folder name creation in Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, filesystems

Preventing illegal file and Folder name creation on a Windows 2003/2008 file server is the goal. We know from articles like [How do I check if a given string is a legal / valid file name under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows) that for some reason the file system allows creation of illegal file/folder chacters and paths that exceed the limitations of Windows. I need the following question answered:

1. How to remove cabability to
   create file or folder creation in
   NTFS that contains invalid
   characters?
2. Can you remove the
   POSIX subsystem from Windows to fix
   this issue?
3. How does disabling
   8.3 dos name creation factor into this issue?
4. Will any of these
       fixes prevent linux clients from
       creating windows compliant files?

Comment: This sounds like a Serverfault question.

Answer (score 0):

Our app has a module that enforces naming rules based on the lowest-common-denominator idea, usually using Windows' rules.  Most of our clients use Windows so this isn't much of an issue for us.  A few use *nix and they grudgingly accept the limitations.