# Obtaining a canonical file path

Tags: ocaml, filepath

In OCaml, how can I obtain a [canonical file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100299), equivalent to Java's `File.getCanonicalPath()` (that is, a normalized absolute path)?

Module `Filename` has a `dirname` function, but it does not normalize file paths such as `/etc/../usr` into `/usr`, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JaneStreet Ocaml Core has [Filename.realpath](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.07.00/doc/core/Filename.html).

Also, google for `ocaml realpath` (see  [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) in C; you might code some wrapper for it)

Comment: Realpath is useless in case of non-existing files/directories.

Comment: Yes, but so what? Is the OP's question mentioning that?

Comment: It didn't, just a reminder that `realpath` is not generic enough.

Answer (score 2):

Our [phat](https://github.com/solvuu/phat) library defines `normalized` rather precisely. The library is overkill for most use cases, but we wrote it for applications that deal heavily with the file system. We'll release to opam soon, but for now you'll have to do a couple of pins. Here is a full working example:

```
$ opam pin add solvuu_build https://github.com/solvuu/solvuu_build
$ opam pin add phat https://github.com/solvuu/phat.git
$ utop
# #require "phat.pure";;
# module Phat = Phat_pure.Std;;
# Phat.(abs_dir "/a/../b/./c/d/" |> ok_exn |> normalize |> to_string);;
- : string = "/b/c/d"
```