# Path.GetFullPath unexpected behavior on "DriveLetter:SomeDirectory"

Tags: c#, path

I am trying to get whether a directory path is valid or not using the `Path` class as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137165/3670437) answer.

However, while I expect `Path.GetFullName("C:SomeDirectory")` (without any slashes) to throw an exception, it returns `C:\Windows\system32\SomeDirectory`.

Also, if I write `Directory.Create("C:SomeDirectory")` it tries to create the directory again under `C:\Windows\system32`.

When I try to enter `C:drivers`, for example, to address bar in windows explorer I get error `Windows cannot find file. Check the spelling and try again.`

Command line gives an error on `cd C:drivers`, too.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: cd to `c:\windows\system32` then try `cd c:drivers`. All will work. Even weirder is that if you eg map the f: drive, then do `cd c:\windows\system32`, `f:`, `cd c:drivers` and `c:` you'll end up in `c:\windows\system32\drivers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, C: just tells it which drive.  The rest of the path must start with root '\' if you want the path to run from root - otherwise it'll just be appended to the current directory.

The Path and Uri methods are very specific about these things.

All Paths are relative to the current working directory - but starting the path with \ makes it relative to the root (of that drive) - its the same on the command line too

Comment: OK, but why this does not work in windows explorer or command line?

Comment: Right, when I write `cd C:Default` on command line while the current directory is `C:\Users`, it goes to `C:\Users\Default`.

Comment: Yup - thats exactly it.