# What is the easiest way to check a string whether it is a represents File name with full path in a correct Format?

Tags: c#, .net, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Figuring out whether string is valid file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067479/figuring-out-whether-string-is-valid-file-path)
>   [In C# check that filename is *possibly* valid (not that it exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/in-c-sharp-check-that-filename-is-possibly-valid-not-that-it-exists)

I have a method that expects a string which represents a file name with its full path.

I want to validate (Guard) this string in terms of its format to see whether it CAN really represent a file name (not the correctness of the path whether it exists or not)?

For example it should not be accepted if it is something like : "123C:\foo\"

What is the easiest way to do this check in C# ?

```
public void LoadFile(string fileName)
{
  var valid = Check if 'fileName' is in valid format.
  if(!valid)
      throw new ArgumentException(....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx):

> In members that accept a path as an input string, that path must be well-formed or an exception is raised.

So you can do something like this:

```
public void LoadFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var path = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(...);
    }
}
```