# how to validate a safe filename with double (.) (.) "fileName ..pdf"

Tags: c#, .net, string, filepath

Im sarching how to create a safe filename in my webapplication I had read a lot of post around here last one [How do I check if a given string is a legal / valid file name under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows) but I can't find the solution for this example when the filename comes in the way "fileName ..pdf" (double dot), the browser can't open the file at least IE and is a safe filename at least for windows,so how can I search for this exception and remove the double dot, what I have by now is the following example (which obviously doesn't remove the double dot:

```
foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) { fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '-'); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do an extra check afterwards and replace the `..` with `.`:

```
foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
    fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '-');

fileName = fileName.Replace("..", ".");
```

Comment: yes in dit, I thougth would be a problem if the file path have an dot in the middle like name.filenam.pdf but that is not a problem, the browser can open the file without problems, I guess this easy approach works thanks