# How to search all directory's except for one C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on an antivirus in C#.
I have one small problem though. 
When it scans the computer's files, it can't access files in AppData.
How would I be able to search all directories except for one?

This is what I got so far(does not work):

```
Directory.GetFiles(path , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => !d.StartsWith("<EXCLUDE_DIR_PATH>")).ToArray();
```

I keep on getting the error

> Access to the path 'c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Application Data' is denied.

Comment: and this doesnt work? whats the question here?

Comment: yeah it does not work. @Sommmen

Comment: Could it be a relative/absolute path name problem? Try illustrate (with directory names listed from you code) what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore folders/files when Directory.GetFiles() is denied access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An access denied exception simply means you are not allowed to access the directory. Windows has several of those, and AppData is one of those. Try running the program as administrator. Do note that you need to

1. be a Windows user part of the Administrators group and
2. your app need to be run elevated.

You can achieve both 1 and 2 by running your program's executable by right clicking and selecting 'Run as administrator' (even if your logged in as an administrator!)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works fine. It seems to be a permission issue. Try running your application with Administrator permissions. [Here is a good SO answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator?rq=1)

However, you will run into another problem - `Directory.GetFiles` will find non-existent files. [Another SO answer to look at for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104451/directory-getfiles-finds-nonexisting-files)

In my testing I ran into non-existent folders in the AppData directory. You will need to tell the program to ignore such directories. [Here is another answer to get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293/access-to-the-path-is-denied-when-using-directory-getfiles)