# How to check whether a path can be created on windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am looking for a C++ routine which will check if a given path can be successfully created on the system? 
The routine should not actually create a path but return true if the path can be successfully created?

Thanks..

Comment: A routine that can predicts things like permission issues, out of disk space, hardware failures? Perhaps you want to redefine the problem as a routine that can check if a string is a valid path name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows

Comment: stat() on the directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code that tries to create the path in a try catch block..

Comment: Yeah but if it succeeds the path will be created.

Comment: This is the only real solution. There's no way to ensure that a path can be created (lots of unexpected things can go wrong at runtime), so when you actually want to create it, you'll *still* have to handle errors. Might as well just do it that way the first time.

Comment: Right. Plus, if you are able to successfully create a directory, you are also able to delete it (if this is not the right time to actually create it). So, no harm done.

Comment: Ageed, but there are a few very simple checks that can be done *before* even attempting to create the path. A difference between *could* and *would*, perhaps.