# Why does File.Exists("c:\filename.txt/") return true?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

For the file `C:\filename.txt`,

```
File.Exists(@"c:\filename.txt/");
```

returns `true`. But when we then try to open with that filename, it fails.

The filename is bad because of the trailing /. But how can we test to know if a file is valid as this tells me it is not only ok, but that the file exists.

**Update:** In a standard command line test app the results are as expected (false). But in my  [custom uri handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) the File.Exists() returns true. It's really bizarre.

Comment: For me it returns false in Linqpad

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows

Comment: I reach the same conclusion as @Sriram. What kind of framework are you running, .NET, Windows Store, anything else?

Comment: I am getting a false in LinqPad as well.

Comment: You're going to need to post more of your code.  Running this in a basic WinForms C# project, it returns false with the trailing slash (but true without it, assuming I've created the file first).  I can't get it to return true with the trailing slash.  I'd like to see how you did it.

Comment: Please show the code of your custom handler so we can recreate the results. You need to give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to re-create the problem or your question will not get any useful answers. I am upvoting because this is a good question, but I have to vote to close as the question is un-answerable without a SSCCE.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The problem is the SSCCE I created works as expected. It only has this problem when the code is called as a custom UI handler and you can't set that up as an SSCCE (I think).

Comment: I would still try my best to create one and include the steps you do to re-create the problem in the custom UI handler. Without steps for us to re-create a custom UI Handler that behaves the same as yours I don't think anyone will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when querying a system folder, file visualization is the culprit in this kind of issue. IE the file exists at the virtual store location but not in the actual queried path. As a result, attempting to open it will fail. So, before you state that the file doesn't exist. . . you should make sure it **really** doesn't exist.

Comment: You can look for the file in the VirtualStore on Windows 7 in this path:
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\.