# SetDllDirectory fails with some unicode symbols

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I'm using SetDllDirectory (SetDllDirectoryW actually) to make some delay-loaded libraries load from a specific directory.
It goes like

```
if (SetDllDirectory(directory.c_str()) == 0)
{
    ERROR_MSG("Failed to set the current dll directory [%d]\n", GetLastError());
}
```

So everything works fine, most of the time, `"f:/source/trunk 11"` is fine and so on
But when it's called with `"f:/source/trunk Gest hieß es !№;%()_@#$^&"`, i get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` from GetLastError. I am able to create a directory with such a name and i can work with it.
But what's so special with `SetDllDirectory` and `"Gest hieß es !№;%()_@#$^&"`? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the use of international characters. The problem is the semi-colon. For whatever reason, `SetDllDirectory` does not accept a semi-colon in the path that you supply. I cannot find any documentation for why this is so, but it's quite easy to check that it is so.

```
SetDllDirectoryW(L"aa")
```

will succeed, but

```
SetDllDirectoryW(L"a;a")
```

will fail.

The same is true for `AddDllDirectory`. Any path containing a semi-colon is rejected.

My guess is that internally Windows stores this information in a single string, using semi-colon as a separator. And because of this these functions have to reject paths that contain semi-colons.

Comment: Related: [How check if given string is legal (allowed) file name under Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows) -- alas, I cannot test if this includes the `;`. The MSDN example only lists a few.

Comment: One work-around that might work is to use the Short filename (DOS style).