# Windows filename - How to check if filename would be valid?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, filenames

I wanted a function, possibly amongst [Path Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559(v=vs.85).aspx), that would check if file-name would be valid. By valid, I meant if character present in the string are all valid (having no `?`, `>` etc, for example). But sadly, there is no function. Browsing through the net, and SO, I found few techniques, none of them I liked, or found solid.

- Using a regular expression to check the contents of filename.
- Creating a file name, possibly in `%TEMP%` path of the system. If creation fails, the filename is (*possibly*) invalid. Otherwise, it is valid (and therefore, delete the file).
- Write up a function, that checks if invalid characters are present in the filename (e.g. `?:*>`)

An extended form of function would be to check all invalid names (like `AUX`, `CON` etc), but that's not an issue (at least for now).

Is there any documented/undocumented function, that I might have missed, which would reliably check if filename (**not** pathname) is valid.

Comment: There's a nice little function which will remove illegal characters for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776472%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: You cannot technically figure out if a filename is not valid that is not a pathname, since the validity of a filename depends on the underlying file system as well.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @gha.st, that's true, but the OS would know it. And, I am asking OS supplied function only.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, but `PathGetCharType` doesn't solve the problem. It works for path, but not (only) for filename.

Comment: @Ajay You can have (many) different file systems on one OS. In fact, you may even end up with file systems that are not shipped with your OS.

Comment: @gha.st I was only concerned about NTFS on Windows. I will reconsider WhenEver sun rises from west.

Comment: @Ajay No need to be snarky. Adding the NTFS restriction makes the problem significantly easier. As to the sun rising from the west: Consider that USB sticks are not usually preformatted with NTFS and that many a NAS solution uses a linux core with an ext filesystem internally.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-string-is-a-legal-valid-file-name-under-windows/62888

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: the [`PathCleanupSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776472%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function is now deprecated and no longer supported. Refer to the `Requirements` section at the end of the linked page for details.

---

Thanks Connor, for the function. For other readers, the function name is [`PathCleanupSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776472%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Using which I have implemented following:

```
bool IsLegalFileName(LPCWSTR filename)
{
    WCHAR valid_invalid[MAX_PATH];
    wcscpy_s(valid_invalid, filename);

    int result = PathCleanupSpec(nullptr, valid_invalid);

    // If return value is non-zero, or if 'valid_invalid' 
    // is modified, file-name is assumed invalid
    return result == 0 && wcsicmp(valid_invalid, filename)==0;
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if this solved the problem for you.

Comment: `PathCleanupSpec` strips out colons that indicate the NTFS data stream to use such as `"file.ext:ads"` or `"file.ext:ads:$DATA"` for a record named "ads". The default for `"file.ext"` is the anonymous stream `"file.ext::$DATA"`.

Comment: Note that PathCleanupSpec is listed as deprecated.  It might not exist in future versions of Windows.