# Can I let git warn me when I try to add a file with a file name which is invalid on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, git

I am developing on a Linux machine. It happened once that I added a file 'sin(x):2.tex' or something similar. This caused some trouble for a friend who uses a Windows system and wanted to clone my repository.

I know there are much more [invalid file names on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) than on Linux. Is there a possibility to make git warn me if I try to add such an invalid file name to my repository?

Comment: Have you tried a [`pre-commit` hook](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: No, I didn't know that this was possible. I have to take a look at that. Thanks! (I see pre-commit and post-commit at a first glance, but no pre-add ... but I have to read that more carefully to see if / how it works)

Answer (score 2):

You can see a good example of [pre-commit hook in this gist](https://github.com/t-b/git-pre-commit-hook-windows-filenames/blob/master/pre-commit), in reference to [this answer about valid Windows names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888/6309)

```
# A hook script to check that the to-be-commited files are valid
# filenames on a windows platform.
# Sources:
# - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888
# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit", move it to ".git/hook" and make it executable
```

It uses [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A -z $against
```

Note that a `pre-commit` hook is a [client-side hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks), meaning it has to be deployed in all repos for all users.
And it can be bypassed (with `git commit --no-verify`).

Another approach is to set a `pre-receive` hook ([server-side hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)) which will block any push including invalid filenames.