# How to use Regular expression to test for FIle Names with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use this open source image uploader: https://github.com/blueimp

The documentation says that the function to match on File Type can be used to match on file name also.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/7d46990486ff08acfc001b6368b09bce6712c2c2/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js

Can anyone see a way to use this to match on and restrict special characters in the file names?

Here is the RegEx that will match the characters that I specifically want to exclude. I am trying to prevent end users from using special characters in file names, instead of just depending on training them.  English is the only concern in this case.

```
[&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%]
```

Here is the snipit from the source code (open source) that would evaluate it. Full code available at the link above.

```
 // The File Upload Validation plugin extends the fileupload widget
// with file validation functionality:
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

    options: {
        /*
        // The regular expression for allowed file types, matches
        // against either file type or file name:
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        // The maximum allowed file size in bytes:
        maxFileSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
        // The minimum allowed file size in bytes:
        minFileSize: undefined, // No minimal file size
        // The limit of files to be uploaded:
        maxNumberOfFiles: 10,
        */

        // Function returning the current number of files,
        // has to be overriden for maxNumberOfFiles validation:
        getNumberOfFiles: $.noop,

        // Error and info messages:
        messages: {
            maxNumberOfFiles: 'Maximum number of files exceeded',
            acceptFileTypes: 'File type not allowed',
            maxFileSize: 'File is too large',
            minFileSize: 'File is too small'
        }
    },

    processActions: {

        validate: function (data, options) {
            if (options.disabled) {
                return data;
            }
            var dfd = $.Deferred(),
                settings = this.options,
                file = data.files[data.index],
                fileSize;
            if (options.minFileSize || options.maxFileSize) {
                fileSize = file.size;
            }
            if ($.type(options.maxNumberOfFiles) === 'number' &&
                    (settings.getNumberOfFiles() || 0) + data.files.length >
                        options.maxNumberOfFiles) {
                file.error = settings.i18n('maxNumberOfFiles');
            } else if (options.acceptFileTypes &&
                    !(options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.type) ||
                    options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.name))) {
                file.error = settings.i18n('acceptFileTypes');
            } else if (fileSize > options.maxFileSize) {
                file.error = settings.i18n('maxFileSize');
            } else if ($.type(fileSize) === 'number' &&
                    fileSize < options.minFileSize) {
                file.error = settings.i18n('minFileSize');
            } else {
                delete file.error;
            }
            if (file.error || data.files.error) {
                data.files.error = true;
                dfd.rejectWith(this, [data]);
            } else {
                dfd.resolveWith(this, [data]);
            }
            return dfd.promise();
        }

    }

});
```

Edit: Some things I have tried:

Thanks for the quick responses. Some things I have tried here:
Many of these return the the match even it it the name is preceeded by an invalid character. 
See http://regexr.com/3be9o
I don't want asdf&ghjik.jpg to match as valid.

I guess I really want a-z A-Z 0-9 - _

```
[^&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%]([\w]+\-*[\w]+)+(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)

([^&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%])?([\w]+\-*[\w]+)+(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)

([\w]+\-+[\w]+)+(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)

[^&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%]*(\.jpg)|[^&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%]*(\.png)|

[^&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%]*(\.gif)|[^&~@#$^*()_+=/:?;\\|<>"',!%]*(\.jpeg)
```

Comment: Instead of disallowing specific things, specify what's allowed.

Comment: If it's just regex, `[A-Z,a-z,0-9]` only allowed for filenames; otherwise, output error.  If you want to include certain characters as well, like period, hyphen, underscore, just prepend an escape character `\.,\_,\-`.  I'm not sure about the best way in javascript.  Why don't you include what you've tried?

Comment: @ILMostro_7 that character group will also include the comma `,` as that is not a delimiter inside of character groups. Those have no delimiter, it's just a bunch of chars. Also, there is no need to escape an underscore `_` and you do not need to escape a dash `-` if it's the last thing in the character group. That gives `[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]`.

Comment: Edited original with some clarifications based on feedback. Thanks for quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

As @Nit pointed out in a comment, white-listing rules is always better than black-listing. This means always try to specify what's allowed rather than what's forbidden as it is very easy to miss something (Did you think of pound sign? Non-English alphabets? UTF characters in general?)

As a start you can use the very simple `[\w\.\- ]`

> The **\w** metacharacter is used to find a word character.
>
> A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.

For a good explanation on what are good/bad file names in Windows take a look at [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888/5020253)

Comment: Thanks @Stoyan
When I try that it selects partial matches that are invalid. How do I prevent that? See  http://regexr.com/3bed7

Comment: You would want to use `^` and `$` around your regex. This means it should start and end with (i.e matches the whole string) [demo](http://regexr.com/3begv)

Comment: I think that was almost what I needed, but then I also needed to enable the multiline flag (in my regex demo) so that it would only pay attention to a match on a single line.
This appears to be the final version that works.
`/^([\w\.\- ]+(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png))$/gm`

http://regexr.com/3bed7