# Regex to identify valid filepath and filename is too slow

Tags: c#, regex, filepath

I have a C# application that needs to recognize whether a given string is a valid Windows file path that ends in a file name with extension. Currently I have:

```
public static bool IsValidWindowsFilePathWithFileName(string filepath)
{
    string scriptFilePathPattern = @"^[A-Za-z]:(\\\w+(\s*\w+)*)*(\\\w+(\s*\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]\w*)$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(filepath, scriptFilePathPattern);
}
```

This normally works fine. However, if I put in something that ends with a long string, such as

> "C:\Windows\System32\ThisIsALongBadFileName"

it takes several minutes to process. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with one of the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/62771/62576  Also, WIndows filenames are not required to end with an extension.

Comment: Provide examples of what is valid, and what would be invalid. Saying a path is wrong...doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Please stop trying to validate filenames with strings or regular expressions. [That doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007). The only way to validate a filename is to try to create it and see if it throws an exception at runtime.

Comment: Several *minutes*? What are you running this on?

Comment: Why are you not using File.Exists(string path)?

Comment: I'm not using File.Exists because the computer that the path is stored on may not be the same computer where the path is used.

Answer (score 1):

Where possible remove `*` (zero or more) and replace with `+` 1 or more. Every `*` used, adds to the backtracking of the parser. If you know there is not *zero* condition, don't put it in...use the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to simply accept that any file path which doesn't end in a slash is valid, rather than trying to police legitimate filenames.