# Python Pandas: Creating filename before saving dataframe as csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make file name before saving dataframe as csv. Here is my code:

```
import glob
filename = 'Top20Apps' + ' ' +pd.to_datetime("now").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")+'.csv'
```

Then I am trying to check whether the any csv file with same name exists or not by following code:

```
files_present = glob.glob(filename)
    if files_present:
        df.to_csv(filename,index=False,mode='a',header=False)
    else:
        df.to_csv(filename,index=False)
```

When I ran the above code, it throws the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Top20Apps 2021/02/01.csv'
```

Error is showing on the else section. I am not sure where I made the mistake. Any help to fix the issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need change `.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")` to `.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")`, because `/` is not valid value for filename under [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-string-is-a-legal-valid-file-name-under-windows).